# How can I use the `leader` key immediately after hitting Escape in Neovim?

Tags: neovim

Using NVIM v0.6.0 with an empty init.vim config file I can get my `<leader>` key to work after pressing `<ESC>` to exit Insert mode if I do one of the following:

1. Press `<ESC>` twice before pressing the `<leader>` key
2. Press `<ESC>` once then press the `<leader>` key twice
3. Press `<ESC>` and then wait a couple seconds before pressing `<leader>`

Each of those is slower than I'd like. My goal is to be able to hit the `<ESC>` key and then immediately hit the `<leader>` to activate it.

Based off [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/24925/15011) I tried adjusting the `timeoutlen` and `ttimeoutlen` like

:set timeout timeoutlen=300 ttimeoutlen=10

That didn't work. (It did make the leader key disappear faster after it activated though)

Is there a way to only hit the `<ESC>` key one time and then be able to immediately hit the `<leader>` key a single time and have it activate?

Answer (score 0):

The answer in my case was not nvim itself, but tmux. There is a delay after pressing escape in tmux that was the problem. I don't use escape in any way on tmux so I turned if off by updating my `~/.tmux.conf` file to add this:

```
set -sg escape-time 0
```

To give credit where it's due, the answer was provided by [this post](https://github.com/jbranchaud/til/blob/master/tmux/remove-the-delay-on-the-escape-key.md)